# JMS message redelivery on exception in JMS listener

Tags: java, spring, spring-jms

Javadoc for `org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer` states, that if

> "sessionAcknowledgeMode" set to "CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE": Automatic message acknowledgment after successful listener execution; no redelivery in case of exception thrown.

I guess, "no redelivery in case of exception thrown" means, that message would not be redelivered (so, my guess, it would be acknowledged), even if there's an exception thrown in the jms listener. But, well, exception thrown from listener means that call to it wasn't successful, and there should be redelivery due to no acknowledgement.

The question is: 
**What actually should happen with message acknowledgement in case of exception thrown in the jms listener?**

What really happens, might be seen from this stacktrace:

```
at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:98)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:66)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:660)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:620)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:591)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:308)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:246)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1142)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1134)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1031)
```

Line 5 of the stacktrace is of particular interest. Code there basically means, that (mostly) whatever exception thrown from the listener will bypass the ackowledgement which is done in `org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer#commitIfNecessary`. 
 
**That's ok, but what does "*no redelivery in case of exception thrown*" mean then?**

Additional info: 
spring-jms:4.1.2

```
<bean id="someListenerContainerFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="concurrency" value="1-10"/>
    <property name="sessionAcknowledgeMode">
        <util:constant static-field="javax.jms.Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends on which listener container you use; when using AUTO ack mode, the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` acks after the listener returns (i.e. a traditional JMS `MessageListener`). The `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` acks before the listener is invoked, so you need `acknowledgeMode="transacted"` to prevent message loss.

The javadocs in this area were a bit misleading and have been [improved recently](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/c1a9e3484ae28d4af045310b7df5116744bd5f08#diff-fabb5ed58e2afc74376ebd2554690468).

With CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE, you're on your own to do the acks. That doc just means you are at the whim of the broker. According to the JMS message javadoc:

> Messages that have been received but not acknowledged may be redelivered

In my experience it is best to use auto ack with an `SMLC` and transactions with `DMLC`.

Comment: I see, but still nothing changed for `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE`.
I'm using `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`.
And, by the javadocs,  `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` means container will do ack for me *after successful listener execution*

Comment: No; `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` means you are responsible for calling `Message.acknowledge()`. Read the JMS spec.

Comment: I'm asking not about JMS spec, but spring container behavior. If you look at `org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer#commitIfNecessary` you can clearly see, that it does acknowledgement for me automatically after listener execution. Whether this is correct behavior or not is out of the question, coz container javadoc explicitly says exactly that.

Comment: I see - I didn't realize the container does client acks. But, as you say, if the listener throws an exception then the ack is not done. The broker may or may not decide to redeliver. My question is why do you want to use client ack? Use `JmsTemplate.execute()` if you want more control over the consumer.

Comment: Basically, I need exactly what stated in the docs: "_Automatic message acknowledgment after **successful** listener execution_". That's why I don't need more control over acknowledgements. But the last part stating "_no redelivery in case of exception thrown_" is really misleading. Hence the question on SO. If that's the bug in the javadocs I happily fire an issue, but if it isn't, I wanna hear what does this part mean then.

Comment: Use a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` with AUTO acknowledgeMode to get what you want - feel free to open a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR) if you feel the javadoc is misleading.