# DLQ for topics with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic

I'm using Spring Boot and ActiveMQ. I want to send and receive messages from a topic. This is working well. My code looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
        JmsSpike.TestListener1.class,
        JmsSpike.TestListener2.class,
        JmsSpike.Config.class
})
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "spring.activemq.broker-url: tcp://localhost:61616",
        "spring.activemq.password: admin",
        "spring.activemq.user: admin",
        "spring.jms.pub-sub-domain: true", // queue vs. topic
})
@EnableJms
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class JmsSpike {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Test
    public void sendMessage() throws Exception {
        sendMessageInThread();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }

    private void sendMessageInThread() {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("asx2ras", "I'm a test");
            }
        }.start();
    }

    @TestComponent
    protected static class TestListener1 {

        @JmsListener(destination = "asx2ras")
        public void receiveMessage(String message) {
            System.out.println("****************** 1 *******************");
            System.out.println("Hey 1! I got a message: " + message);
            System.out.println("****************** 1 *******************");
        }
    }

    @TestComponent
    protected static class TestListener2 {

        @JmsListener(destination = "asx2ras")
        public void receiveMessage(String message) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Nope");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class Config {

        @Bean
        public RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy() {
            RedeliveryPolicy topicPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
            topicPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(1);
            return topicPolicy;
        }

        @Bean
        public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(@Value("${spring.activemq.user}") final String username,
                                                   @Value("${spring.activemq.password}") final String password,
                                                   @Value("${spring.activemq.broker-url}") final String brokerUrl) {

            ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(username, password, brokerUrl);
            cf.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy());
            return cf;
        }
    }
}
```

- I can send a message
- I receive the message with both listeners
- One listener will always work and just print some console message
- The other listener will always throw an exception

I set the retry to "1", so the failing listener will be called one more time after the exception was thrown. However, after the retry, the message is not delivered to an error queue (or error topic). How can I send the message to an error queue so that I can call the failing listener again later?

Note that I only want to call the failing listener again, not all listeners on the topic. Is that possible?

---

EDIT

Here's my `activemq.xml` (just the `broker` tag):

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

    <destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
          <policyEntries>
            <policyEntry topic=">" >
              <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
              </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
            </policyEntry>
          </policyEntries>
        </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>

    <managementContext>
        <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
    </managementContext>

    <persistenceAdapter>
        <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>

      <systemUsage>
        <systemUsage>
            <memoryUsage>
                <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
            </memoryUsage>
            <storeUsage>
                <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
            </storeUsage>
            <tempUsage>
                <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
            </tempUsage>
        </systemUsage>
    </systemUsage>

    <transportConnectors>
        <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    </transportConnectors>

    <shutdownHooks>
        <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
    </shutdownHooks>

</broker>
```

Comment: Can you post here what is the broker configuration in activemq.xml. Are you using persistence? From official doc: "By default, ActiveMQ will not place undeliverable non-persistent messages on the dead-letter queue."

Comment: @IulianRosca of course. I updated my question.

Comment: Thanks for the update. What I would try to do at this point is to set the maximumRedeliveries to 1 inside activemq.xml. By default the values is set to 6 (http://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy.html). In case after this configuration the messages end up in DLQ, it means there's a problem with the mechanism when the client overrides the broker redelivery policy. You can see the negotiated values (WireFormat) if you enable debug logging.

Comment: @IulianRosca You were right! When I remove the "RedeliveryPolicy" bean from my Java configuration, the message ends up on an DLQ ("ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageDLQd.Queue.asx2ras"). Do you know how I can configure the DLQ on the client side instead of "activemq.xml"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html), you can override the broker configurations on the client side:

> The broker transmits the default delivery policy that he prefers to a
>   client connection in his BrokerInfo command packet. But the client can
>   override the policy settings by using the
>   ActiveMQConnection.getRedeliveryPolicy() method:

```
RedeliveryPolicy policy = connection.getRedeliveryPolicy();
policy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(500); policy.setBackOffMultiplier(2);
policy.setUseExponentialBackOff(true);
policy.setMaximumRedeliveries(2);
```

So, the way you have configured the redelivery policy seems OK.

The only issue that I see is when you create a new instance of `RedeliveryPolicy` and set only a single field `topicPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(1);` all other fields that are primitives will be assigned default values. You should probably set the maximum redeliveries on the existing instance of redelivery policy:

```
RedeliveryPolicy policy = cf.getRedeliveryPolicy();
policy.setMaximumRedeliveries(1);
```

**Edit**

Also, make sure that by using `@JmsListener` is not using `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE`. According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29417096/2231685) the messages will not get redelivered when `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` is used.